# Archive Page Template returns posts instead of page content on Polylang second language

Tags: wordpress, archive, polylang

I have an issue with Polylang and custom archive page template. On my main language my archive page shows page content but on second language it starts looping trough posts.

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: Archive Page Custom */
get_header();

while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;

?>

<?php
 get_footer(); ?>
```

What causes this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. It turns out that under Polylang settings I had to uncheck my custom taxonomies because it completely breaks the site.

EDIT: Never mind this doesn't work because as I turn it off it shows posts from all languages on my archive first page. So it still has to be turned off to filter posts between languages.

So the issue remains. Archive page with default language loads content in from the page and secondary language shows posts for some reason instead of content.

EDIT: It was a conflict with archive-portfolio.php template and also I had custom post type slug named same as my secondary translation so the page broke. I had to rename my archive-portfolio.php template to portfoliotemplate.php and it works now.